# Bootstrap 3 Grid Style Issue with alignment

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I’m trying to create a person place-holder which appears or two of my screens using Bootstrap-3.
I’m trying to create something like below

Image # 1 
http://i.imgur.com/Fj1NCbV.jpg?1

**As you can see I would need the Column 2 and Column 3 to be aligned – as this corresponds to label and value.**

I’m using ASP.Net app with c#. the values (Jason etc.) would be dynamically added from backend using c#.

Now im using the Below code –

```
<div class="container">  
        <div class="row">
            <%--img--%>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="../../images/Person_img.png" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--tr #--%>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <%--1--%>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"> First Name</div>
                        </div>

                        <%--2--%>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"> Last Name </div>
                        </div>
                        <%--3--%>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"> Email</div>
                        </div>
                        <%--4--%>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"> Address</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <%--1-v--%> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"> Jason </div>                            
                        </div>
                        <%--2-v--%>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"> Bourne</div>                        
                        </div>
                         <%--3-v--%>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"> Jasonbourne@test.com</div>
                        </div>
                        <%--4-v--%>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                Street # 1,
                                House No 1,
                                City,
                                State,
                                Country
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Whats happening is –

- The labels are not being aligned with the values.
- Also whenever there is space (First Name) the, both ‘First’ and
  ‘Name’ seem to appear in two different lines

Image # 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlVsg.jpg

Could you advise on where I'm going wrong with this.

ps: i don't have enough point to post image, so im using imgur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the form, you need to conceptually restructure your HTML as follows:

```
row
col, col

row
col, col

row
col, col

....
```

As the content in the col expands, it will push the next row down.

Here's a fiddle showing you how:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwo5v8yw/

I've actually went for this:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">label1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">label2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">value2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">label3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">value3</div>
        </div>
```

As bootstrap takes a new row when the col count his 12.

NB: Drag the JS fiddle middle slider to the left if you have a small monitor ;)